# TimeOut ConnectioString

Tags: c#, sql-server, timeout

Tenho uma dúvida sobre o valor Timeout que pode ser passado na ConnectionString, esse valor é referente a segundos ou milesegundos?

```cs
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="meu banco;provider connection string=data source=servidor;initial catalog=banco;user id=user;password=senha;App=EntityFramework;Timeout=5;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A propriedade Timeout se refere a o tempo limite em **segundos** para criar a ligação com o BD.

Porém o nome correto seria `Connect Timeout`.

Você pode consultar a lista de todas propriedades da connectionString para Sql Server [aqui](https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/)

Comment: obrigado pela observação do nome da propriedade, já corrigi aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Esse valor é em segundos se o seu banco for o sql sever, acredito que mude de acordo com cada banco, uma vez que essa string de conexão é enviada ao DBMS (Data Base Management System), ou seja, ao servidor do banco. Esse parâmetro é responsável pelo tempo limite que a aplicação irá estabelecer a conexão com o servidor DBMS, e não o tempo de execução do comando.

Comment: Entendi agora, @vinicius muito obrigado pela ajuda.